# Problems performing backup operation using RMAN and Oracle 11g XE

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I need to transfer my oracle 11g databases to a new machine. Both machines are using windows 7.

Already found a lot of descriptions how to do that but its really hard if you are not an oracle expert because there is always information missing.

What I tried is this:

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/82720/

But I get stuck at the point where to start the database again in "mounted" mode. After trying "startup mount" I always get "ORA-12514".

So, it is not possible for me, to get the database in a state where I can run the backup operation in RMAN.

Also searched for that problem an found answers what to do but not how do do that.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have to add your database to the listener.ora in ORACLE_HOME\network\admin

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    ....
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = YOURDATABASE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = ORACLE_HOME)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = YOURDATABASE)
    )
  )
```

After you have done that restart the listener.

Comment: Hi Rene! Thank you for your help. But now I run into the next issue during the backup process. After running "Backup database", the process is starting but not ending successfully. I get RMAN-03009: failure of backup command on Channel1 channel at date/time ..." but no additional error. 

ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Comment: Maybe this is a good subject for a new question on stackoverflow, of maybe even http://dba.stackexchange.com/. I must say I don't know a lot about RMAN. The listener problem is something you can encounter just shutting down and starting up the database using sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is an error in your alertlog. can you check database alert log and report any error. you can find the path if alert from v$diag_info. it located in trace directory.